# import json file data into elastic search using logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

i want to import json file data into elastic search.
here is my config file of logstash--

> input {   file {
>       type => "json"
>       path => "C:\Users\Desktop\newJSON.json"
>       start_position => "beginning"     sincedb_path => "\dev\null"
>                         } }
>
> output {
>       stdout {
>           codec => rubydebug
>       }
>       elasticsearch {
>           hosts =>  "localhost:9200" 
>           index => "jsondata1"
>       } }

And here is my json file---

> {
>       "fruit": "Apple",
>       "size": "small",
>       "color": "Red"
>   },
>   {
>       "fruit": "Papaya",
>       "size": "Large",
>       "color": "Yellow"
>       "test" : "sweet"
>   }

i executed above config file using this command----

```
logstash -f logstashcon.conf
```

but i got data like below in elastic search index--

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 10,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "jsondata1",
        "_type": "json",
        "_id": "AWNniXbgMkzPgBTTablA",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "path": "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\newJSON.json",
          "@timestamp": "2018-05-16T06:00:48.302Z",
          "@version": "1",
          "host": "user-102",
          "message": "{\r",
          "type": "json"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "jsondata1",
        "_type": "json",
        "_id": "AWNniXbgMkzPgBTTablB",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "path": "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\newJSON.json",
          "@timestamp": "2018-05-16T06:00:48.694Z",
          "@version": "1",
          "host": "user-102",
          "message": "    \"fruit\": \"Apple\",\r",
          "type": "json"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "jsondata1",
        "_type": "json",
        "_id": "AWNniXbgMkzPgBTTablE",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "path": "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\newJSON.json",
          "@timestamp": "2018-05-16T06:00:48.696Z",
          "@version": "1",
          "host": "user-102",
          "message": "},\r",
          "type": "json"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "jsondata1",
        "_type": "json",
        "_id": "AWNniXbgMkzPgBTTablC",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "path": "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\newJSON.json",
          "@timestamp": "2018-05-16T06:00:48.695Z",
          "@version": "1",
          "host": "user-102",
          "message": "    \"size\": \"Large\",\r",
          "type": "json"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "jsondata1",
        "_type": "json",
        "_id": "AWNniXbgMkzPgBTTablD",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "path": "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\newJSON.json",
          "@timestamp": "2018-05-16T06:00:48.696Z",
          "@version": "1",
          "host": "user-102",
          "message": "    \"color\": \"Red\"\r",
          "type": "json"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "jsondata1",
        "_type": "json",
        "_id": "AWNniXbgMkzPgBTTablG",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "path": "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\newJSON.json",
          "@timestamp": "2018-05-16T06:00:48.698Z",
          "@version": "1",
          "host": "user-102",
          "message": "\"fruit\": \"Papaya\",\r",
          "type": "json"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "jsondata1",
        "_type": "json",
        "_id": "AWNniXbgMkzPgBTTablJ",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "path": "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\newJSON.json",
          "@timestamp": "2018-05-16T06:00:48.699Z",
          "@version": "1",
          "host": "user-102",
          "message": "}\r",
          "type": "json"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "jsondata1",
        "_type": "json",
        "_id": "AWNniXbgMkzPgBTTablH",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "path": "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\newJSON.json",
          "@timestamp": "2018-05-16T06:00:48.699Z",
          "@version": "1",
          "host": "user-102",
          "message": "    \"size\": \"Large\",\r",
          "type": "json"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "jsondata1",
        "_type": "json",
        "_id": "AWNniXbgMkzPgBTTablF",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "path": "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\newJSON.json",
          "@timestamp": "2018-05-16T06:00:48.698Z",
          "@version": "1",
          "host": "user-102",
          "message": "{\r",
          "type": "json"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "jsondata1",
        "_type": "json",
        "_id": "AWNniXbgMkzPgBTTablI",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "path": "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\newJSON.json",
          "@timestamp": "2018-05-16T06:00:48.699Z",
          "@version": "1",
          "host": "user-102",
          "message": "    \"color\": \"Yellow\"\r",
          "type": "json"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Please help me to get correct output
Thank you!

Comment: Read the logstash manual. Also learn to format your question, it's barely legible

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the JSON filter plugin for logstash to structure your output,

For example, if you have JSON data in the `message` field, your filter will be,

```
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
}
```

This is what the documentation says,

> It takes an existing field which contains JSON and expands it into an
>   actual data structure within the Logstash event.

Please read more about [usage and example here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html).